# Lengths must match to compare

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to map values of one dataframe to another.
My dataframes are as follows:

```
df2.head()
    ext_id  credit_debit_indicator  index_name  business_date   trench_tag  trench_tag_l2
0   4SL19N2YQLCU62TY    C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
1   1EXHR74Y2YXBN4AM    D   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
2   OI0001WMRUD C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
3   OI0001WKKXA C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
4   SGW7000490024199    C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
```

and

```
mapping_df.head()
trench_code trench_level    fink_code   fink_level
0   COM0101001  4   PREPAID_01  2
1   COM0101002  4   PREPAID_01  2
2   COM0101003  4   PREPAID_01  2
3   COM0101099  4   PREPAID_01  2
4   COM0101999  4   PREPAID_01  2
```

I tried:

```
df2['fink_sub_tag_key'] = mapping_df.apply(
        mapping_df["fink_code"] if mapping_df["trench_code"] in df2['trench_tag'].values else np.nan,
        axis=1,
    )
```

Which raises:

> ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

It is the truth that I have values of different lenghts on mapping_df.trench_code. But don't know how to cope around it.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

we need minial example for answer

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'a'], ['B', 'b'], ['C', 'c'], ['D', 'd']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

`df`

```
col1    col2
0   A   a
1   B   b
2   C   c
3   D   d
```

**Code**

if col1's value in ['A', 'B', 'C'], take col2's value, if not NaN

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
s = df['col2'].where(df['col1'].isin(lst))
```

`s`

```
0      a
1      b
2      c
3    NaN
Name: col2, dtype: object
```